# What explains the semantic sameness in 'Verb + preposition + Direct Object' and 'Verb + Direct Object'?

Tags: english, verbs

Why can prepositions following a verb not  affect the meaning of Verb Phrases that differ by only a preposition? I.e., what explains the semantic sameness between Verb Phrases that differ by only a preposition, but that both mean the same? I can't divine why, but to me 1 looks wrong and 2 correct.

### Example 1: [**agree + DO (Direct Object)**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22agree+a+price%22&tbm=bks&ei=8iz9WYLpPMnrmQGcs7GACQ&start=10&sa=N&biw=1408&bih=622&dpr=2.73) vs. [agree on](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22agree+on+a+price%22&tbm=bks&ei=eS_9WdH_PIm3mwGe6I6IAw&start=30&sa=N&biw=1408&bih=622&dpr=2.73)/with DO

> [1.1. [p. 93 Top.](https://books.google.com/books?id=cOQmDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT141&dq=%22agree+a+price%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCqvu49qPXAhXJdSYKHZxZDJAQ6AEIUDAG#v=onepage&q=%22agree%20a%20price%22&f=false) [*Textbook on Contract Law* (2016 13 ed.)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/textbook-on-contract-law-9780198732808?lang=en&cc=hu) ] In English law, even where there is only an agreement between the parties to **agree a price**, it 
>   seems that the courts will enforce that agreement if at all possible once performance has begun.
>
> [1.2. [p. 187 Middle.](https://books.google.com/books?id=1jooDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&dq=%22agree+a+price%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir8LXH9qPXAhWKSyYKHSGrCs84ChDoAQgnMAA#v=onepage&q=%22agree%20a%20price%22&f=false) [*A Practical Approach to Conveyancing* (2017 19 ed.)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/a-practical-approach-to-conveyancing-9780198787563?cc=ca&lang=en&) ] If you are fortunate enough to **agree a price reduction** and you act for both borrower/ 
>   buyer and lender then, subject to your duty of confidentiality to your borrower client, 
>   you have a duty to inform the lender of the price reduction.

vs.

> [1.3. [p. 198 Top.](https://books.google.com/books?id=STMYHOUu5aYC&lpg=PA198&dq=%22agree%20on%20a%20price%22&pg=PA198#v=onepage&q=%22agree%20on%20a%20price%22&f=false) [*White-Collar Crime: The Essentials* (2012.)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010WIK3DS) ] Price fixing offenses occur when competitors **agree on a price** at which goods or services should be sold.

### Example 2: allowed + DO vs. allowed to DO

Robert Schütze. [*European Union Law* 2 ed. 2018](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/eu-law-9780198714927?cc=ca&lang=en&). p. 107. All emboldenings are mine.

> From there, the Court reasoned as follows:
>
> > Consequently, observance of the general principle of equal treatment, in particular
> >     in respect of age, cannot as such be conditional upon the expiry of the period
> >     allowed **[TO]** the Member States for the transposition of a directive intended to lay down
> >     a general framework for combating discrimination on the grounds of age …

Comment: Whether a verb is transitive or not is pure convention.

Comment: _Agree a price_ appears to be limited to British legal language. It's certainly not colloquial English. However, your question might be worth answering if you can get some better examples to show what you're talking about.

Comment: This phenomenon is known as (symmetric) differential object marking (asymmetric DOM being alternation between DO marking and null marking, in languages that have an optional DO marker).